# Trying to get folder sizes for all users directory

Tags: windows, powershell, ntfs

I am trying to write a powershell that will look at a network share and write out to a CSV the full name of the share and the size in MB or GB of those folders for each user home directory folder.

This is my code so far:

```
$StorageLocation = '\\wgsfs01\USERDIR\USERS'
$Roots = Get-ChildItem $StorageLocation | Select Fullname
ForEach ($Root in $Roots) { (Get-ChildItem $Root -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum }
```

I believe there is something wrong with my ForEach statement as this is my error message

**Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:@{FullName=\wgsfs01\USERDIR\USERS' because it does not exist.**

I appreciate any advice and thank you in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I think with network shares you could eliminate errors by prefixing your path with `FileSystem::`, so `FileSystem::\\wgsfs01\USERDIR\USERS`. This ensures that `Get-ChildItem` knows that it is a path for the [`FileSystem Provider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_filesystem_provider?view=powershell-7.1), and then use the full object rather than just Selecting the `FullName` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that FullName contains a DirectoryInfo object, you have two options;

1. Change your select to ExpandProperty which will change it to a string of the full path.

   Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname
2. Refer to $Root using the property FullName which is a property on the DirectoryInfo Object.

   Get-ChildItem -path $Root.FullName -Recurse

This is one solution to what you are trying to achieve, note that errors (e.g. access denied) are ignored.

```
Get-ChildItem $StorageLocation | ForEach-Object {

    $sizeInMB = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        FullName = $_.FullName
        SizeInMB = $sizeInMB
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you your code worked great and my issues is now resolved.

Comment: @JRN, the first `Get-ChildItem` should probably use the `-Directory` switch so that it only returns directory items.